# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ - Error: Driver 'sdhost-bcm2835 is already registered, aborting. What is that and how to solve it?

Tags: pi-3b+, boot-issues

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and a microSD 64GB.
I am going trough the boot process following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYd8_AwtS4g).

This is what I have:

1. MicroSD card 64Gb (it is working) formated to FAT32 using [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html).
2. OS - [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/). ubuntu-mate-18.04.2-beta1-desktop-armhf+raspi-ext4.img.xz. Inside my linux I ran `unxz ubuntu-mate-18.04.2-beta1-desktop-armhf+raspi-ext4.img.xz` what gives me an image `ubuntu-mate-18.04.2-beta1-desktop-armhf+raspi-ext4.img`
3. Than I run the `Win32 Disk Imager` sending the img to the microSD.

When I turn on the raspberryPi I get the follow error
[image]

Also I have many bcm2835 files in the boot sdcard

[image]

Does someone knows this error and how to solve it?

### Update

This issue seems to be related to the beta version.

This is the [link](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus-ubuntu-mate-installation-error-driver-sdhost-bcm2835-already-registered-aborting/19300) to follow this issue.

Comment: Using the official supported operating system Raspbian isn't an option?

Comment: It is an issue in the version. Take a look in the update.

Comment: That's the reason why I ask for Raspbian as in option. I know that Ubuntu didn't support the RPi 3B+ for more than a year. Seems they do not have much interest to support the RasPi in general. I suggest to use Raspbian.